# Equation image added to two editors instead of intended one ckeditor in single page

Tags: ckeditor, editor, rich-text-editor, ckeditor5

I have two editor instances (one as question and second as answer) on a single web page and implemented a custom **`Add Equations`** plugin.
Whenever I'm trying to add an equation in the question editor, It gets added in both question and answer editor instead of only question editor. I figured out that there was a problem with my custom equation plugin. I have tried in multiple ways but unable to achieve the expected output.

(**Note** : Rendering two editor instance using element reference(viewChild) in angular 7)

**ckeditor-tool.ts**
`@ViewChild('editor') public editorRef: ElementRef;`

**ckeditor-tool.html**

`<textarea class="editor" #editor name="question" placeholder=""></textarea>`

Both editor are rendering properly.

Custom plugin code is below :

```
import Plugin from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core/src/plugin';
import { modelToViewAttributeConverter } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image/converters';
import ButtonView from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ui/src/button/buttonview';
import ClickObserver from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine/src/view/observer/clickobserver';
export class MathText extends Plugin  {

    init() {
        const editor = this.editor; 
        const view = editor.editing.view;
        const componentFactory  = editor.ui.componentFactory;

        this._defineSchema(); 
        this._defineConverters();
        this._defineListenerModalToCK();
        view.addObserver( ClickObserver );

        componentFactory.add('MathText', locale => {
            const view = new ButtonView(locale);
            view.set({
                label: 'Add Equations',
                withText: true,
                tooltip: true
            });

            // Callback executed once the image is clicked.
            this.listenTo(view, 'execute', () => {
                openModel();
                console.log("MathText Plugin called");
            });
            return view;
        });

        this.listenTo( editor.editing.view.document, 'click', ( evt, data ) => {
            // if ( data.domEvent.detail == 2 ) {
            if ( data.domEvent.detail == 1 ) { // temp
                console.log("_editorToPopupdoubleClickHandler");
                this._editorToPopupdoubleClickHandler( data.domTarget, data.domEvent );
                evt.stop();
            }
        }, { priority: 'highest' } );


    }

    _defineSchema () {
        const schema = this.editor.model.schema;
        schema.extend( 'image', {
            allowAttributes: [ 'data-mathml','advanced' ]
        } );
    }
    _defineConverters() {
        const conversion = this.editor.conversion;
        conversion.for( 'downcast' ).add( modelToViewAttributeConverter( 'data-mathml' ) );
        conversion.for( 'upcast' ).attributeToAttribute( {
            view: {
                name: 'img',
                key: 'data-mathml'
            },
            model: 'data-mathml'
        } );
        conversion.for( 'downcast' ).add( modelToViewAttributeConverter( 'advanced' ) );
        conversion.for( 'upcast' ).attributeToAttribute( {
            view: {
                name: 'img',
                key: 'advanced'
            },
            model: 'advanced'
        } );
    }
    _defineListenerModalToCK () {
        var model = this.editor.model;
        var selection = model.document.selection;
        window.addEventListener('setDatatoCK', (data) => {
            model.change( writer => {
                 const imageElement = writer.createElement( 'image', {
                    src: data.detail.imgURL,
                    'data-mathml': data.detail.latexFrmla,
                    advanced : data.detail.advanced
                } );
                model.insertContent( imageElement, selection );               
            } );
        })
    }

    _editorToPopupdoubleClickHandler(element, event) {
        if (element.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
            var latexStr = element.getAttribute("data-mathml");
            var advanced = element.getAttribute("advanced");
            if (typeof event.stopPropagation != 'undefined') { // old I.E compatibility.
                event.stopPropagation();
            } else {
                event.returnValue = false;
            }
            loadDataFromCkEditortoPopup({latex:latexStr,advanced :advanced});
            // event.stop();
        }

    };

}
```

#### ✔️ Expected result

[image]

#### ❌ Actual result

[image]

### Other details

- Browser: Google Chrome Version 78.0.3904.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
- CKEditor version: CKEditor 5
- Installed CKEditor plugins: ckeditor5-editor-classic,ckeditor5-image,ckeditor5essentials,ckeditor5-basic-styles,ckeditor5-core,ckeditor5-ui

**Please help me with the same.**